# How to randomly choose an item from a list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, random, colors

I'm creating a game in buildbox, and i'm trying to create a script that is written in javascript(I am not a javascript coder) to choose randomly from a range of colors, for example:

```
color_list = [color1,color2,color3]
```

So that it in this list it picks color2 randomly taking into account color 2 is: (255,0,0) in RGB

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
let randomColor = color_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * color_list.length)];
```

As mentioned in [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)